# Python flask builtins.ValueError ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
db = get_db()
query = 'UPDATE pages SET title = ?, text = ? WHERE id = ?',[request.form['title'], request.form['text'], page_id]
db.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

I get an error:

> builtins.ValueError ValueError: operation parameter must be str

I tried this:

```
query = 'UPDATE pages SET title = (?), text = (?) WHERE id = (?)',[request.form['title'], request.form['text'], page_id]
```

Didn't help.
What do I do?

Comment: have you tried `query = 'UPDATE pages SET title = ?, text = ? WHERE id = ?',request.form['title'], request.form['text'], page_id`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes

Comment: sorry that was just a wild guess. Check the type of all your parameters. Maybe one is an integer for instance.

Comment: The question has *Flask* in the title, but you tagged Django?

Comment: @idjaw just a misprint, automatically did this